# Delete similar records in SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having trouble figuring out how to delete records from a table in an SQLite database where there is nothing unique about the records, so what I mean is that I have a table where there is a lot of deliberate duplication.

My app is an Exercise Tracker app where you can store exercises with sets, reps and weight, the table I am trying to go into and delete a record is the one where it stores reps and weight, so they could easily be the same.

Here is my code:

```
public static final String CREATE_CARD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + CARD_TABLE + "(" + CARD_ID
    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + CARD_NAME
    + " TEXT )";

public static final String CREATE_CARDINFO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + CARD_INFO_TABLE + "(" + CARD_ID2
    + " INTEGER, " + CARD_NAME2
    + " TEXT, " + CARD_WEIGHT
    + " REAL, " + CARD_REPS
    + " INTEGER, "
    + " FOREIGN KEY " + "("+ CARD_ID2 +")"+ " REFERENCES " + CARD_TABLE + "("+CARD_ID+"));";
```

Inserting into the table

```
    public void insert(String name) {
    open();
    database.beginTransaction();
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME, name);

    // Insert the row into your table
    database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_TABLE, null, newValues);
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    close();
}

public void insert2(long id, String name, double weight, int reps) {
    Log.v("id", id + "");
    open();
    database.beginTransaction();
    ContentValues newValues2 = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues2.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_ID2, id);
    newValues2.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_NAME2, name);
    newValues2.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_WEIGHT, weight);
    newValues2.put(DataBaseHelper.CARD_REPS, reps);

    // Insert the row into your table
    database.insert(DataBaseHelper.CARD_INFO_TABLE, null, newValues2);
    database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    database.endTransaction();
    close();
}
```

Edit: what if I wanted to delete all of the records that have the id of the primary key? because I could just delete them all and add a new list, as I have a temporary arraylist which shows the items, I can just insert each of them into the database after all of the database items have been deleted.

Comment: You need to provide table structure and what do you want new primary key is.

Comment: I think, if you know which record you want to remove, then you can write the logic, how to get that record...

Comment: give some example data and point what you want to delete! now I see a pile of useless code

Comment: I have changed the question, how do i delete all of the data in a table where the id matches the paramter I give it? (int id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have an `id` of the record you want to delete, then the `delete()` method is here to help:

```
database.delete( table, "_id=?", new String[]{ id } );
```

if you want to delete records based on some other fields:

```
database.delete( table, "someField=? or anotherField=?", new String[]{ val1, val2 } );
```

if you have a list of id's, you can delete all the records in one sit:

```
String ids = concatenateIds(); // should return a string "11,22,33,44"
database.delete( table, "_id in (" + ids + ")", new String[]{} );
```

Note, that you can pass the positional params of the query only as `String`s

Comment: thanks for a great answer, but what if there is duplicate data and I only want to delete one? but there is nothing unique about them and I dont know the rowid?

Comment: you have to narrow your `where` clause down to include more conditions. thus you will delete records more precisely. If you still have problems with deletion of records you desire, you have to redesign your DB-schema to make it more "delete-friendly"